# WordPress - How to enable Scandinavian characters in permalink?

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying to find a way to enable some Scandinavian characters to the permalinks. I've searched, but I can't seem to find any way to do this. I've seen some plugins that might allow it, but what I'm wondering is if there's a way to add some code to functions.php to disable the prevention. I prefer not using plugins, as they usually add a ton of stuff that I don't need.

Is there a way to allow for ÆØÅ in permalinks, by adding code to functions.php (basically without messing with the WordPress installation)?

Edit:

Maybe with a filter?

```
function enable_scandinavian_characters() {
    ...
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'enable_scandinavian_characters');
```

Comment: I would advise against this, as the permalinks are essentially your web URLs. If a website is on the web, you want to stick the bare standard characters that can be access by all users. Going against this, will seriously limit people being able to access your website. In this day and age, accessibility is something Google take seriously. Make your site as accessible as possible!

Comment: That is a valid point, although the only reason I want this is so Google recognizes the keywords in the URL. I've seen better results with say example.com/kål than example.com/kal for the keyword kål.

Comment: It's also for testing. I'm going to compare the results of both permalink structures, and see if it really does make a difference. Would also be good to know how to actually do this, just for learning.